# Error while trying to do ssl striping :" iptables: No chain/target/match by that name"

Tags: linux, ssl, kali-linux

I am getting this error while trying to do SSL-striping:

> iptables: No chain/target/match by that name

While running command:

```
iptables -t nat -A -PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

in Kali Linux.

Answer (score 3):

You have one extra dash in your command. The correct command is:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```